# Wix Installer: Failed to wait for child to connect to pipe

Tags: wix, windows-installer, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to install software on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and several installers are failing, including:

> [Visual C++ Redistributable 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)
>   [MS Build Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760)

The log files have similar error messages leading me to think there is a general problem with Wix based installers running on this server:

> [0ED0:0F78][2015-03-27T16:57:08]: Burn v3.6.3542.0, Windows v6.1
>   (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path:
>   C:\Users\dsmith\Downloads\vcredist_x64.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated
>   BurnPipe.{B557C8BF-F4EF-414C-BEE4-4548A61377E5}
>   {D6146B39-D884-46C5-81DF-91DE3E882A1B} 3568'
>   [0ED0:0F78][2015-03-27T16:57:08]: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleLog' to value
>   'C:\Users\dsmith\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20150327165708.log'
>   [0ED0:0F78][2015-03-27T16:57:08]: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value
>   'C:\Users\dsmith\Downloads\vcredist_x64.exe'
>   [0ED0:0F78][2015-03-27T16:57:08]: Error 0x800700e5: Failed to wait for
>   child to connect to pipe. [0ED0:0F78][2015-03-27T16:57:08]: Error
>   0x800700e5: Failed to connect to elevated parent process.
>   [0ED0:0F78][2015-03-27T16:57:08]: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
>   [0ED0:0F78][2015-03-27T16:57:08]: Variable: WixBundleLog =
>   C:\Users\dsmith\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20150327165708.log
>   [0ED0:0F78][2015-03-27T16:57:08]: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource =
>   C:\Users\dsmith\Downloads\vcredist_x64.exe
>   [0ED0:0F78][2015-03-27T16:57:08]: Error 0x80070218: Failed to write
>   message type to pipe. [0ED0:0F78][2015-03-27T16:57:08]: Error
>   0x80070218: Failed to post terminate message to child process cache
>   thread. [0ED0:0F78][2015-03-27T16:57:08]: Error 0x800700e5: Failed to
>   run per-user mode.
>   [0ED0:0F78][2015-03-27T16:57:08]: Exit code: 0x800700e5, restarting: No

Is there any way to fix the server, registry settings to check, etc?

Comment: It looks like a similar question was raised here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675360/wix-3-8-burn-failed-to-elevate-package-installer

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this is about building a new installer. I'm trying to use an existing Microsoft installer and getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread and I haven't tried this but in the wix it looks like you're trying to use the burn protocol for wix communication to visual c++ distribution and that particular .exe might not support the burn protocol for communicating it's progress.  Try setting the protocol setting to none and maybe wix can handle that better.

I think the reason is probably because wix is expecting the underlying exe/installer for vc++ to get some form of communication when you tell it protocol="burn".