# Create a Single MSI installer

Tags: wix, wix3.7, wix-extension

I have developed a application which is in a 32-bit and 64-bit format. These applications require corresponding registry entries as well. I am delivering these as separate packages for 32-bit and 64-bit using WiX.

Now my requirement is to create a single installer which installs the components based on OS configuration. I tried using Bootstrapper to bundle my packages.

My bootstrapper code looks as below:

```
<Bundle Name="Bootstrapper" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="MYCOMPANY" UpgradeCode="b24f74ca-883c-4572-9479-37d92d733aa0">
  <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
  <Chain>
    <ExePackage Id="source1" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" SourceFile="32\Sample.exe" InstallCondition="Not VersionNT64" />
    <ExePackage Id="source2" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" SourceFile="64\Sample.exe" InstallCondition="VersionNT64" />
  </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

My bootstrapper output is MSI. When I run the MSI I am getting `MainEngineThread is returning 1620` in the verbose log.

Please suggest how can I bundle two EXE's to get single MSI package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wix installer bundle produces corrupt "msi"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134807/wix-installer-bundle-produces-corrupt-msi)

Answer (score 0):

Error 1620 isn't particularly nasty - it just means it can't open the MSI file, and the simplest explanation for that is that your directory structure is incorrect and the exe is calling the MSI install with the incorrect location or name for the MSI file.